# Truncate part of string in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I have 2 `NSAttributedString`'s that I append together and then set it to be the text in the UILabel pictured. I want the first attributed string to truncate if it's going to be longer than 2 lines so that the second attributed string still shows up. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Why not to have two UILabels instead?

Comment: Consider splitting this into two labels, one for each.

Comment: I was previously using 2 labels, but then changed to 1 label after having some problems..I guess I'll try again.

Comment: Did you end up getting a solution to this? Or did you have to use two labels?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way will be to create two separate labels to display this text. The first one will display bolded text and the second one rest of the text. You will have to set `NSLineBreakMode` for the first attributed string as in example below:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


NSDictionary *attributes = @{/*yourattributes */NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style};
NSAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:YOUR_TEXT attributes:attributes];
```

You can even resign from using `NSAttributedString` in case you split your text into two separates labels. Instead you can use `UILabel` method to customize text appearance.

```
 label.font = font;
 label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```